# Handlebars Error with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I have an issue with this function:

```
            function setGalleryTemplate() {
                var projectData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName) ),
                    template = Handlebars.compile( $('#gallery-template').html() );

                $('#Gallery').html( template(projectData) );
            };
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="Gallery">
    <script id="gallery-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <ul class="field-list">
            {{#each this.project.modules}}
                <li class="field-item">{{this.id}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
   </script>
</div>
```

Its called when an image is clicked and its supposed to show some details from a json file. This works fine, if an image is clicked the very first time. If it is clicked a second time (or another image) I get this "Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined".

The whole thing works also very fine if the ."html" is replaced by ".append" which isnt really what I want. I would like to "replace" the content (.replaceWith doesnt work either), not append new content.

Comment: If `undefined` is being passed to `Handlebars.compile()`, then there are at least times when no element is found by `$('#gallery-template')`. Can you share the related markup as well? And, is that markup being altered by other parts of the script?

Comment: the markup is never altered except by this function. I found the "undifined" very strange, since it works everytime with .append(template(projectData)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<script>` is part of the `<div>`'s content, setting the `.html()` will also remove the `<script>` from the document, rending it unavailable for the next use.

You'll want to either `compile` the `template` only once, so it doesn't depend on the `<script>`'s presence.

```
var galleryTemplate;

function setGalleryTemplate() {
    // compile on-demand, but only once
    if (!galleryTemplate)
        galleryTemplate = Handlebars.compile( $('#gallery-template').html() );

    var projectData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName) );

    $('#Gallery').html( galleryTemplate(projectData) );
}
```

Or, adjust the markup so the `<div>` and `<script>` are siblings rather than parent/child, so the `<script>` remains in the document while the `<div>`'s contents are replaced:

```
<div id="Gallery"></div>
<script id="gallery-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <!-- ... -->
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I read the answer it seemed like a no-brainer :)